# Accessing individual elements of char pointer inside a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a struct defined as

```
typedef struct {
char *somechar;
} Random;
```

I instantiate a struct like this -

```
Random *r=(Random *)malloc(sizeof(Random));
```

How to individually assign characters one by one to somechar? 
I"ve used

```
r->somechar+0='b';
r->somechar+1='a';
```

and this doesn't work.

Comment: Standard warning: Do not cast `void *` as returned by `malloc` & friends.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you need to allocate the data pointed by `char* somechar`: you are allocating space for the `struct` which contains the pointer, not the pointed data. You need to allocate it separately

```
Random *r = malloc(sizeof(Random));
r->somechar = malloc(20); // allocate space for 20 characters
```

Mind that you don't need to cast the result of `malloc` since in C a `void*` can implicitly be converted to any other pointer type. In addition you must make sure that the value returned by `malloc` is a valid address (hence it's `!= NULL`) to be sure that the heap allocation didn't fail.

Finally to access the individual elements of the `char*` you have two options:

- using the correct index access operator, so `r->somechar[1] = ..`
- using pointer arithmetic directly, `*(r->somechar+1) = ..`

The latter is similar to what you were trying but you need to use the dereference `*` operator to tell the compiler that you want to assign to the value pointed by the address.

Don't forget that you need to deallocate memory too, for both `somechar` and `r` by calling `free(r->somechar)` and `free(r)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef struct {
    char *somechar;
} Random;
```

Requires first to allocate the struct itself:

```
Random *r = malloc(sizeof(*r));
```

and then an array `somechar` has to point to. Without this, it will be uninitialized, invoking *undefined behaviour* if you dereference it.

```
r->somechar = malloc(MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH);
```

`MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH` has to be set to the max. number of entries you want to store into that `char` array. As `sizeof(char)` is defined `1` by the standard, no need to specify this explicitly.

Note that you should not cast `void *` as returned by `malloc` & friends. Whoever tells you should read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

**Caution:**

- Always check the result of system functions. `malloc` can fail, returning a *null pointer*. Dereferencing such is *undefined behaviour* and can make your program crash - if you are lucky (if not, you will not notice anything, but get strange behaviour - like [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)).
- If you want to store a C-string in that `char` array, account for the trailing `'\'`
- Note that all `malloc`ed memory is uninitialized. If you want zeroed memory, use `calloc`.
- `free` both allocated blocks! Use the reverse order of allocation.

If using C99 or C11 (recent standard), you can use a flexible array member and avoid the second allocation:

```
typedef struct {
    char somechar[];    // must be last member of the struct
} Random;

...

Random *r = malloc(sizeof(*r) + MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH);
```

This will allocate the struct with the array of the given size in a single block.